# Can a vector $v$ of Hilbert space be expressed as a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $B=\{b_1,...,b_n,...\}$ be a countable linearly independent subset of $H$ such that $\overline{span(B)}=H$

Is it true that for each $v \in H$ we can write
$$v=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n $$
where $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b_n \in B $

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\overline{span(B)}=H$, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $g_n \in span(B)$, such that $|g_n-h| \to 0$.

Let $h \in B^{\perp}$.

We can write $g_n= \sum_{k=1}^{r_n}a_{n,k} b_{n,k}$, while {$a_{n,k}$}$_{k=1}^{r_n} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, and {$b_{n,k}$}$_{k=1}^{r_n} \subseteq B$.

You get that: $<g_n,h>= < \sum_{k=1}^{r_n}a_{n,k}b_{n,k} >=\sum_{k=1}^{r_n}a_{n,k}<b_n,h>=0$.

According to Cauchy Schwartz we also know that:

$|<h,h>|=|<h-g_n,h>+<g_n,h>|=|<h-g_n,h>| \leq |h-g_n||h| \to 0$.

So $B^{\perp}=\varnothing$. From the Gram-Schimdt process you get a countable orthonormal basis $E \subset span(B)$ which satisfies $span(E)=span(B)$.

You then get that every $h \in H$ can be written as $h= \sum_{i=1}^\infty <h,e_i>e_i$, while for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $e_i \in span(B)$.

Comment: thanls so much for your answer

Comment: You're welcome.